# List Cognito Users in React web app

Tags: reactjs, amazon-cognito

This is my first cognito project. I am making an admin page which will have read only access to all Cognito Users and their attributes.  I have looked through aws-amplify and aws-amplify-react and cannot figure out how to get them to access ListUsers function or something similar. Does anyone have an example of how this is done in React.

I am considering saving User data in a separate Dynamodb table which I can easily access.  I am also wondering which is cheaper?  Read/Writing User Attributes in Cognito or in Dynamodb?  I can only find documentation on number of active users in Cognito and nothing on how often their attributes are read/wrote to.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue, but what I ended up doing was creating a lambda function for this and using the SDK to access this information. You could create an API endpoint through the mobilehub CLI and then the lambda it creates you can edit in your local express project under the desired get request of your choosing and put in the following:

```
var cognito = require('aws-sdk/clients/cognitoidentityserviceprovider');    

app.get('/users', function(req, res) {
    let params = {
        UserPoolId: userPoolIdHere,
        AttributesToGet: [
            'COGNITO_ATTRIBUTE_NAME',
            'COGNITO_ATTRIBUTE_NAME
        ];
    };

    cognito.listUsers(params, function(err, data) {
        if(err) {
            res.json(err);
        } else {
            res.json(data);
        }
    });
}
```